# How do I fire a custom event from a child window back to parent window?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, user-controls

I am looking to close the application when I click a cancel button in a login page, but I don't want to do it in such a way that Window 2 closes itself, but by sending some notification to Main Window, and Main Window closes the application. Here's the code that I have so far:

(in loginPage)

```
Public Event CloseApp As EventHandler

Private Sub CancelButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles CancelButton.Click

    DialogResult = False
    RaiseEvent CloseApp(Me, New EventArgs)
End Sub
```

(In Main Window)

```
Public loginPage As New LoginPage

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    AddHandler loginPage.CloseApp, AddressOf Me.ShutDownJobChangeWindow
End Sub

Private Sub ShutDownJobChangeWindow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Application.Current.Shutdown()
End Sub
```

This does not work. I am new to handling events so if anyone could help explain what's wrong with this I would be very grateful to you!

P/S: I am not too sure about C# too would appreciate code in VB.NET.

Comment: As far as i can tell your code looks ok. Did you set any breakpoints in both Click and CloseApp event handlers to see if they get hit?

Comment: Yup it did. actually It worked and I learned something. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look into your Project Settings / Application / Shutdown Mode, and have it set to 'On explicit shutdown'.

(i assume this is the instance of LoginPage that is hooked to the event handler that is raising the event.)
try also to set a breakpoint in event handler to see if it is reached.